# Restructure name in excel from (Last, First) to (First Last)

Tags: excel, excel-formula

### Goal

Create a helper column that converts the value of a cell from `Last, First` to `First Last`

---

The below formula works fine. `A1` contains `Last, First` and the below formula converts to desired output.

```
 A2 = MID(A1,SEARCH(", ",A1)+2,LEN(A1))&CHAR(32)&LEFT(A1,SEARCH(",",A1)-1)
```

The question is, **can anyone provide a more concise formula to achieve same result**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't bother with a formula, use [Flash Fill](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/using-flash-fill-in-excel-3f9bcf1e-db93-4890-94a0-1578341f73f7).  If you really need a formula = `=MID(A1&" "&A1,FIND(", ",A1)+2,LEN(A1)-1)`.

Comment: If `,` is not included in the `FIND` this won't work for last names with spaces such as `de Gaulle, Charles`.